# Left Join only return values where UserID match

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, entity-framework

Left join return duplicate products when 1 or more user save same product.

I solved the problem in SQL query.here's a query:

```
select p.ProductID,  
       (case when c.UserID = 3 then 'true' else 'false' end) as flag
    from product as p  
    left join SavedItem as c on product.ProductID = c.ProductID and
      c.UserID = 3
```

can't figure out how to do in a Entity framework.

```
left join SavedItem as c on product.ProductID = c.ProductID and
 c.UserID = 3
```

Left join can be solve like this:

```
join c in SavedItem on p.ProductID equals c.ProductID into lj
    from c in lj.DefaultIfEmpty()
```

`c.UserID = 3` where to place this?

Comment: Those are two conditions. You need `as c on new { p.ProductID, 3 } equals new { c.ProductId, c,UserId }`

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var query=  from product in context.Products
            from SavedItem in context.SavedItems.Where(c=> c.ProductID = product.ProductID && c.UserID == 3).DefaultIfEmpty()
            select new {
                        ProductID=product.ProductID,
                        Flag=(SavedItem==null || SavedItem.UserID != 3) ? false : true
            };
```

Answer (score -1):

Here! I found the solution.

```
from product in context.Products
      join c in context.SavedItems 
      on new { p1 = (int?)product.ProductID , p2 = (int?)cat.UserID } 
      equals new { p1 = c.ProductID ,p2 = c.UserID} into lj
      from c in lj.DefaultIfEmpty()
                   select new{
                        ...
                       flag = (c.UserID == cat.UserID ? "true" : "false"),
                         ...
                             }
```

Comment: IDK why someone gave neg vote. It run as I want. :(